# Dimension 3 quadratic forms are isotropic iff they are zero in the Witt ring?

Tags: quadratic-forms

In the paper *Quadratic Forms over $\mathbb C[t_1,t_2]$* by K. H. Kim and W. Roush (https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82242112.pdf), they mentioned on page 77 that over $\mathbb C(t_1,t_2)$, forms of dimension 3 are isotropic if and only if they are zero in the Witt ring.
I haven't understood this point. Suppose that we have an isotropic form $q=<1>\perp<-1>\perp<a>$ where $a$ is a non-trivial element in $\mathbb C(t_1,t_2)^\times/\mathbb C(t_1,t_2)^{\times 2}$, then the class of $q$ in the Witt ring $W(\mathbb C(t_1,t_2))$ is determined by its anisotropic part and $q\sim <a>$ which shouldn't be zero in the Witt ring (if I'm not wrong)?

Comment: You're definitely right, all the more so as you don't need $a$ to be non-trivial: there is a correspondence between elements of $W(\mathbf{C}(t_1,t_2))$ and isometry classes of  anisotropic forms over $\mathbf{C}(t_1,t_2)$ so that the class of $q$ is $<a>$ and $<a>$ is clearly nonzero in the Witt ring (for example using that correspondence). Do the authors use this affirmation in the rest of the article?

Comment: Oh yes that's right! I don't think they used this affirmation elsewhere; they mentioned this mainly to justify why they started considering dimension 4 (but not lower dimension) forms as conter-examples to the Hasse principle.